# Memory leak with FXCanvas

Tags: javafx, memory-leaks, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on Eclipse e4 RCP application where I have one SWT part. Using JavaFX interoperability with SWT I have added javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas. After I create a javafx.scene.Scene with 50000 javafx.scene.control.Button and hook it to the canvas, application memory jumps to 1.5gb.

Problem starts when I close that part, application does not release a memory. When I open that part again, memory jumps to 2.something gb.

Part class:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

import javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class StressTestJavaFXPart
{
    private Scene scene;
    private FXCanvas canvas;

    private final int columns = 100;
    private final int rows = 500;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(final Composite parent)
    {
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        canvas = new FXCanvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).span(0, 0).applyTo(canvas);

        final Pane pane = new Pane();

        for (int i = 0; i < columns ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows ; j++)
            {
                final Button button = new Button(String.format("%s : %s", i, j));
                pane.getChildren().add(button);
                button.setLayoutX(100 * i);
                button.setLayoutY(100 * j);
            }
        }

        final ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(pane);
        scene = new Scene(sp);
        canvas.setScene(scene);

        parent.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void widgetDisposed(final DisposeEvent e)
            {
                canvas.dispose();
                System.gc();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are very welcome! Thanks

Comment: If most of your RCP is JavaFX it might be better to use [e(fx)clipse](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) which provides a completely JavaFX version of e4 with no SWT needed.

Comment: I'm dependent on some e3 views like Project Explorer. I have to use e3 and compatibility layer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using reflection:

```
parent.addDisposeListener(disposeEvent -> {
     //release Pixel Buffer via Reflection -> prevents memory leak
     try {
        Field pixelBuffer = FXCanvas.class.getDeclaredField("pixelsBuf");
        pixelBuffer.setAccessible(true);
        pixelBuffer.set(this, null);
     } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
     }
  });
```

Worked well for me.